Delphi 12 : RestRequest.Resource Access Violation
I'm using the IGN REST API to get ground elevation at geographic coordinates:
RESTClient.BaseURL := https://wxs.ign.fr/calcul/alti/rest
procedure TAffiche.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PointLong     : string;
  PointLat      : string;
  JsonValue     : TJSONValue;
  Elevation     : string;
  Resource      : string;
begin
  if not DetectionConnexion then
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('Internet connection not availlable.');
  end
  else
  begin
    try
      MemoData.Clear;
      PointLong := LongRef;
      PointLat  := LatRef;
      Resource  := 'elevation.json?lon=' + PointLong + '&lat=' + PointLat + '&indent=true';
      RESTRequest1.Resource := Resource;
      RESTRequest1.Execute;
      JsonValue := RESTResponse1.JSONValue;
      Elevation := JsonValue.GetValue<string>('elevations[0].z');
    finally
      JSONValue.Free;
      RESTClient1.Free;
      RESTRequest1.Free;
      //      RestResponse1.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

The code works fine on the first click of the button. But when I click a second time, an error occurs:

RestRequest1.Resource : Access violation

I tried to free memory with RESTResponse1.Free, but the same error occurs.
When I exit the program, the same error occurs.
I can't figure out what the issue is.

As @SilverWarrior says in the answer, you're freeing controls that don't belong to you in your loop. If you didn't create them within that block of code, don't free them in that block of code. You're cutting off the limb you're standing on while facing the tree, and the unchangeable result of that is that you end up on your backside. When you drop components on the form, they become owned by the form, and the form will free them when it is freed. The takeaway here: If you didn't create it in code, don't free it in code, and if you DO create it but don't use nil as the owner, don't free it.

Rule of thumb: don't do .Free if you haven't done .Create on the same thing earlier.

The problem lies in you freeing and thus destroying the RESTRequest1 and RESTClient1 from within your button OnClick event method. So, when you click your button again they no longer exist, hence why you get an Access Violation exception.
Now, based on their naming, I'm guessing these are actually components that you have placed on your Form at design-time. If so, then the form is their owner and will take care of their destruction when it gets destroyed.
You may also want to check REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.ResetToDefaults, which resets both RESTRequest and RESTResponse to their default state, so you can make multiple requests one after another without the need of destroying and then recreating the whole RESTRequest component every time.

Same thing with the RESTResponse1.JSONValue object, too.  It is owned by RESTResponse1, so you should not be freeing it, either.
